# TensorFlow's Mirrored strategy, batch size and Back Propagation

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, distributed-computing, batchsize

i'm dealing with the training of a Neural Network on a multi-gpu server. I'm using the MirroredStrategy API from TensorFlow 2.1 and i'm getting a lil confused.

I have 8 GPUs (Nvidia V100 32GB)

- I'm specifying a batch size of 32 (how is it managed? Each gpu will have a batch of 32 samples? Should i specify 256 as batch size -32x8- ?)
- When and how is Back-propagation applied? I've read that the MirroredStrategy is synchronous: does it imply that after the forward step all batches are grouped into one batch of size 32x8 and after that back-propagation is applied? Or Back-prop is applied once for each batch of size 32 in a sequential manner?

I really want to be sure on what kind of experiments i submit to the server since each training job is really time consuming and having the batch size to change (and back-prop) based on the number of available GPUs affects results correctness.

Thank you for any help provided.

Comment: If you are providing batch size of 32 each GPU will get a batch of 32 samples, if you are using `tf.data.dataset` with `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy`

Comment: @SwapnilMasurekar what about the Back Propagation? Could you provide a reference for your statement?

Comment: Backpropagation is applied separately on each replica and weights are aggregated using a certain strategy such as 'all reduce' algorithm, etc. You may refer to 'Key Point' mentioned this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MirroredStrategy) to verify the batch size doubt

Comment: Thanks @SwapnilMasurekar. I'm actually using generators but I suppose that still the back-propagation is done separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using MirroredStrategy, the batch size refers to the global batch size. [You can see in the docs here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#using_tfdistributestrategy_with_tfkerasmodelfit)

> For instance, if using MirroredStrategy with 2 GPUs, each batch of size 10 will get divided among the 2 GPUs, with each receiving 5 input examples in each step.

So in your case if you want each GPU to process 32 samples per step, you can set the batch size as `32 * strategy.num_replicas_in_sync`.

Each GPU will compute the forward and backward passes through the model on a different slice of the input data. The computed gradients from each of these slices are then aggregated across all of the devices and reduced (usually an average) in a process known as AllReduce. The optimizer then performs the parameter updates with these reduced gradients thereby keeping the devices in sync.